# Add zipped shapefiles to a react-leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, shapefile, react-leaflet

I would like to add shapefiles in a zipped folder to a react leaflet map. I have tried converting them to JSON format and reading them using this package => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-shapefile
I don't get any errors but nothing is displayed on the map. However, when I upload the JSON file to https://mapshaper.org/, the shapes are visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own `react-leaflet` component using shpjs library to load a shapefile using React & Leaflet.

Install shpjs using `npm i shpjs --save`

Then create a `Shapefile comp`:

```
...
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import shp from "shpjs";

function Shapefile({ zipUrl }) {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {
    const geo = L.geoJson(
      { features: [] },
      {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
          var out = [];
          if (f.properties) {
            for (var key in f.properties) {
              out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
          }
        }
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    shp(zipUrl).then(function (data) {
      geo.addData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

Then use it like a child on react-leaflet's Map component:

```
 ...
 import zipUrl from "./TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip";
 import Shapefile from "./Shapefile";
  ...

<Map center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }} ref={mapRef}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <Shapefile zipUrl={zipUrl} />
    </Map>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-map-e7cr0?file=/src/Shapefile.jsx)

Comment: I don't understand how did u manage to decompress/read the zip file in order to treat it... Also, could you add an upload button to your demo in order to choose which zip file you want to treat ?

Comment: This solves the original question, but unless your shapefile is changing, it might be better to just convert the shapefiles to GeoJSON one time and use GeoJSON, since this solution just does the conversion at runtime every time.

Comment: @ckeeney... I actually also have an alternative to use react-native-maps instead of leaflet, but so far I didn't found an approach in react-native-maps to read zipped shapefile (.*shp, .*shx, .*dbf, .*prj, etc). GeoJSON could be better approach in my opinion, great catch, appreciated it. Thx